# Installing Wine on Kali Linux Rolling, where to start?

Tags: kali-linux, wine

I am new to Kali Linux (or any other Linux distribution) and I am attempting to install Wine to use the software Metatrader4 which is a platform for forex trading (32-bit if I am not wrong). I have no such a structure to make this questions so I am going on my own, apologies in advanced for that:

Let's see first my Linux Distribution:

> root@kali:~# lsb_release -a
>
> No LSB modules are available.
>
> Distributor ID:   Kali
>
> Description:  Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
>
> Release:  kali-rolling
>
> Codename: kali-rolling

And Kernell Version:

> root@kali:~# uname -a
>
> Linux kali 4.9.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.6-3kali2 (2017-01-30)
>   x86_64 GNU/Linux

And my repositories are:

> root@kali:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
>
> deb http ://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
>
> deb-src http ://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
>
> deb http ://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main

And all the time that I try to install wine (when I press TAB to see which options come up with WINE word):

[image]

So if I am an amd64 architecture (because it exists i386 & amd64 on kali, rigth?) and software Metatrader4 (MT4) is 32bit:

- Should I have to install wine64 or wine32 in order that MT4 (32bit) can be installed on this Linux Distribution? What is it wine64-bin, winetricks, etc?
- Should I have to add an specific Wine repository (ppa) for my current kali-rolling version? Does it exists?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Kali is a Linux distribution specifically geared towards professional penetration testers and security specialists, and given its unique nature, it is NOT a recommended distribution if you’re unfamiliar with Linux or are looking for a general-purpose Linux desktop distribution for development, web design, gaming, etc." [http://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux](http://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux)

Comment: Bit of a late comment but the only thing I have to say about 'wine' is that `virtualbox` (or whatever VM you choose) can run native Windows (did I really say that word? Let me go and wire brush my tongue) and the `guest additions` allow you to pass files back and forth.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, you should install 32bit wine.
In order to that, you can simply add 32bit architecture, and update your repo list:
`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get update`

Run `sudo apt-get install wine` after this.

Comment: Hello Doriclazar, thanks for your answer. I am glad you answered that ... Let me post you the outputs. Thanks